# Combining SQL Server Stuff statements to get single rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an interesting problem. I have two T-SQL `STUFF` statements. In this example I have used union. This displays the results in two rows.

What I’d like to do is to combine these results so that it returns a single row. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. The solution should be able to copy with either stuff statement returning null.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is the code

```
SELECT
    (SELECT
         STUFF((SELECT (' ' + mod_orders.mod_no + '<br>')
                FROM mod_serials
                INNER JOIN mod_orders ON mod_serials.mod_id = mod_orders.mod_id
                INNER JOIN mod_order_items ON mod_orders.mod_id = mod_order_items.mod_id AND mod_order_items.item_id = 170
                WHERE     
                    (mod_serials.serial_id = 62 AND 
                     mod_serials.date_implemented IS NOT NULL)
                ORDER BY mod_serials.serial_id 
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''))
UNION

SELECT
    (SELECT     
         STUFF((SELECT (' ' + char_data_mv.char_value + '<br>')
                FROM char_data_mv
                WHERE (char_data_mv.object_id = 62 AND char_data_mv.char_id = 177)
                ORDER BY char_data_mv.row_id 
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')) as [Impl]
```

Example data:

```
Row1 - 00001<br> 00005<br>
Row2 - PMB 12345<br>
```

Combined results would be:

```
00001<br> 00005<br> PMB 12345<br>
```

Comment: What do the 2 rows that you get look like? And what does the 1 row you want look like?

Comment: Also - what do you mean by "The solution should be able to copy with either stuff statement returning null"? I'm afraid I can't understand what this means.

Comment: Please edit your answer rather than just posting more comments.

Comment: Ok that format didn't work.  Fundamentally they'll both be strings.  The bit about null means that if the first stuff returned results but the second didn't  return any, the combined results would still show the first results.

Comment: Sooooooo you have one column and two rows, and you want two columns with one row? Or what? You say "Combined results" - should the 2 strings just be concatenated? Please be precise about what you are asking for - we can't help you if we don't know what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UNION` statement returns all of the rows from the first table, and then all of the rows from the second table together in one big table - so this is why you are getting 2 rows.

Instead, you can just add 2 strings together with the '+' operator. You also want to return a string if the other is null, and adding nulls begets nulls. So use the ISNULL function to give an empty string instead.

```
SELECT
ISNULL((SELECT     STUFF
((SELECT     
(' ' + mod_orders.mod_no + '<br>')
FROM         mod_serials
INNER JOIN mod_orders ON mod_serials.mod_id = mod_orders.mod_id
INNER JOIN mod_order_items ON mod_orders.mod_id = mod_order_items.mod_id AND mod_order_items.item_id = 170
WHERE     (mod_serials.serial_id = 62 AND mod_serials.date_implemented IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY mod_serials.serial_id FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')),'')
+
ISNULL((SELECT     STUFF
((SELECT     
(' ' + char_data_mv.char_value + '<br>')
FROM         char_data_mv
WHERE     (char_data_mv.object_id = 62 AND char_data_mv.char_id = 177)
ORDER BY char_data_mv.row_id FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')),'') as [Impl]
```

Note that you need to remove bothe the `UNION` and also the first `SELECT` after it - which is creating the second table.

Comment: good answer, never thought it would be that simple.  Thanks for your help